# iPhone: how to dealloc custom cell labels

Tags: iphone, uitableview

hi i am working on UITableView custom cell for twitter, for each cell i am adding UIImageView(userPhoto), UILabel(name), UILabel(tweet), UILabel(Data), This i have to dealloc all elements,

please go through the attached Image of INSTRUMENT TOOL alloc screen shot

when i run the Instrument tool, it showing some are not dealloc, how to dealloc,
this is my code

//Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
 static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];


if(!cell) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:nil];

    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UILabel *name  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(72,3,242,15)] ;
name.text   = (NSString*)[(Tweet*)[tweetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] userName];
[name setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13]];
name.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:250 green:250 blue:210 alpha:0.5];
[name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];



UILabel *date  = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,3,130,15)] autorelease];
date.text   = (NSString*)[(Tweet*)[tweetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] created_at];
[date setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
date.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:250 green:250 blue:210 alpha:0.5];
[date setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];



UILabel * tweetLabel  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(72,20,242,60)] ;
tweetLabel.text   = (NSString*)[(Tweet*)[tweetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] tweet];
tweetLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
tweetLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:252 green:148 blue:31 alpha:1];
[tweetLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
[tweetLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,10,58,60)] ;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[(Tweet*)[tweetArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] image_url]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[myImage setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:data]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:myImage];
[cell.contentView addSubview:tweetLabel];
[cell.contentView addSubview:name];
[cell.contentView addSubview:date];
```

[myTweetActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [myTweetActivityIndicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];

```
return cell;
```

}

please guide me 
Thank you[image: This image for instrument tools one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
```

For other labels, you can probably use

```
 [date release]; [tweetLabel release]; [name release]; [myImage release];
```

Comment: hi Harinder, all those UIImage and UILabels released, and i did autoreleased, it is showing some leakages in NSUrl,   [myImage setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:data]]; //this line alot this with this,,,, even i release also UIImage and UILabel also, it showing dellocation is not occurred, please tell me   
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to send a `release` message to all the objects that you have allocated using `init`/`alloc` (name, date, tweetLabel, myImage) as soon as you're finished with them (for example, after `addSubview`). Note that according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a), the view is retained by the receiver.

Comment: Thank you Irene, i did it in code but i miss it in post to you, i am getting trouble in, like this lines NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [myImage setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:data]]; thank you, please check this and tell, how to release this NSData object data, if i am releasing that userPhoto is not coming, if not it is not deallocation how to deal with this

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

[myImage setImage: [UIImage imageWithData:data]];
[data release];
data = nil;

In this case, we are manually releasing the memory allocated. I hope, this works